# Heroku error after Atlassian Bamboo deploy

Tags: heroku, bamboo

I am using the Atlassian Bamboo Heroku plugin to build and deploy my Java web app to Heroku. The build executes successfully and the war file is then uploaded to Heroku where it is now supposed to be available, however, I get the standard Heroku application error page and can see the following in my Heroku logs:

```
 2012-11-11T12:41:12+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 11, 2012 12:41:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Error listenerStart
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 11, 2012 12:41:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set web app root system property when WAR file is not expanded
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.setWebAppRootSystemProperty(WebUtils.java:137)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:117)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:45)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2012-11-11T12:41:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
2012-11-11T12:41:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 11, 2012 12:41:19 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
2012-11-11T12:41:19+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [2,144] milliseconds.
2012-11-11T12:41:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 11, 2012 12:41:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
2012-11-11T12:41:19+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Context [/] startup failed due to previous errors
2012-11-11T12:41:19+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: Context [/] failed in [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] lifecycle. Allowing Tomcat to shutdown.
2012-11-11T12:41:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 11, 2012 12:41:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
2012-11-11T12:41:19+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Shutting down log4j
2012-11-11T12:41:19+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

If I install the application war from my console (using git push heroku master) it all seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if I want to use Log4jConfigListener, it only works for an expanded WAR. The Bamboo Heroku plugin must be deploying it as unexpanded, which is causing my issue. I will remove the Log4jConfigListener, and reconfigure the logging another way.

From the Spring logs (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jConfigListener.html):

> Bootstrap listener for custom log4j initialization in a web
>   environment. Delegates to Log4jWebConfigurer (see its javadoc for
>   configuration details). WARNING: Assumes an expanded WAR file, both
>   for loading the configuration file and for writing the log files. If
>   you want to keep your WAR unexpanded or don't need
>   application-specific log files within the WAR directory, don't use
>   log4j setup within the application (thus, don't use
>   Log4jConfigListener or Log4jConfigServlet). Instead, use a global,
>   VM-wide log4j setup (for example, in JBoss) or JDK 1.4's
>   java.util.logging (which is global too).

Comment: Hi Annie, James from Atlassian Bamboo here. Seems like an issue on the Heroku side. It might be worth [getting in touch with Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/support-channels) if the problem persists.

Comment: The Bamboo plugin deploys a WAR file to Heroku. Expanded WAR is currently not supported. Expanded WAR projects can be deployed with git push: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner